# Exception with shared_ptr invoking make_shared(Args...) c++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I've got a weird behavior and after having spent several hours, I'm finally here.
I have a class DataModel, belonging to its Wrapper. More exactly, the Wrapper instance object has a shared_ptr of DataModel

Wrapper.h :

```
class Wrapper 
{
    shared_ptr<DataModel> model;
}
```

This pointer is initialized in the constructeur with nullptr so as to be initialized after.

Wrapper.cpp :

```
Wrapper::Wrapper(/* few args here*/) : model(nullptr) { ... }

Wrapper::init(Args...)
{
    model =  std::make_shared<DataModel>(Args...)
}
```

Somewhere else in a Supervising class (which contains a shared_ptr of Wrapper)

```
SupervisingClass::SomeFunction()
{
    Wrapper->init();
}
```

And it throws the following exception :

First-chance exception at 0x000000013FB621C4 in CSGeo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000018.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

```
        MyApp.exe!std::swap<std::_Ref_count_base * __ptr64>(std::_Ref_count_base * & _Left, std::_Ref_count_base * & _Right) Line 53    C++
        MyApp.exe!std::_Ptr_base<DataModel>::_Swap(std::_Ptr_base<DataModel> & _Right) Line 316 C++
        MyApp.exe!std::shared_ptr<DataModel>::swap(std::shared_ptr<DataModel> & _Other) Line 662    C++
        MyApp.exe!std::shared_ptr<DataModel>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<DataModel> && _Right) Line 597  C++
        MyApp.exe!Wrapper::init(const QStringList & recentProjects, bool insertNewVirtualProject) Line 83   C++
        MyApp.exe!SupervisingClass::SomeFunction() Line 137 C++
```

If I try to reset my model in the init function, it crashes as well. Any idea ? 
I'm lost this time. And it's not the first time I got troubles with reset function and shared_ptr, I think there is something I miss. And why would the operator= be called, considering that the pointer isn't initialized, c++ should only call the good constructor and forwarding Args, nope ???

It might be relevant to add that before, the model was directly included in the Supervising class (just cut past the code), and I inserted a wrapper between them to get more code clarity with hundreds of lines. And yes, it used to work before.

Thanks by advance for your time

Comment: Not enough context to be able to answer this question without guesswork, I'm afraid. Recommend writing yourself a [mcve] and editing your question to include it if the writing doesn't make the solution obvious. Also worth running a few tests to ensure you don't have a bug in the `DataModel` destructor.

Comment: *"reading location 0x0000000000000018"*. It seems you call method on nullptr. Are you sure that the instance of  SupervisingClass` is not `nullptr`. Navigating in the callstack should show you the nullptr object anyway.

Comment: When `SupervisingClass::SomeFunction()` calls `Wrapper->init()`, chances are that the `Wrapper` pointer is null. Where is the code in `SupervisingClass` that assigns a value to `Wrapper` before `init()` is called on it?

Comment: Ohh, I'm so ashamed. As you suggested @RemyLebeau , the `Wrapper` pointer was null. It didn't even cross my mind cause the debugger told the problem was around operator= of the Model. I don't really understand how it can cross the init function, considering the object is null... Thanks everybody

Comment: @QuentinTealrod calling a method on a null object pointer is technically undefined behavior, but in practice it usually works fine up until the method tries to access a member of the object via its `this` pointer, then it crashes. In your case, when calling `this->model.operator=()`. If you don't access `this`, it usually doesn't crash.